# Update certain nested field values in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a document in mongo db and the documents are as following

```
{
  "Name": "student1",
  "marks": {
    "MP1": [
      70,
      80
    ],
    "MP2": [
      60
    ]
  }
}
```

If I remove the marks 60 for MP2 and 70 for MP1 then I want the output to be like

```
{
  "Name": "student1",
  "marks": {
    "MP1": [
      80
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried with Mongodb pull command but its not working as expected and I am not that familiar with the pull command. Any suggestions as to how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
"$addFields": {
  "marks": {
    "$map": {
      "input": {
        "$objectToArray": "$marks"
      },
      "as": "m",
      "in": {
        k: "$$m.k",
        v: {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$$m.v",
            "as": "v",
            "cond": {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$ne": [
                    "$$v",
                    70
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$ne": [
                    "$$v",
                    60
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
   }
   }
  },
  {
  "$addFields": {
  "marks": {
    "$arrayToObject": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$marks",
        "as": "m",
        "cond": {
          "$ne": [
            "$$m.v",
            []
          ]
        }
      }
    }
   }
   }
  }
 ])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6ZqJQBTC_cJ)

Explanation:

1. Convert the mark object to array to so it is easier to walk over all the values without to care what the key name is and filter values 60 & 70 using $map/$filter
2. Filter the mark array for empty values [] and convert back the mark array to object as to the initial document structure.

If you need to update the document you can use the aggregation with update as in the example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NohETgaGKq_)

Comment: thanks.. somehow the direct mongo queries look complex to comprehend.. I need to translate this to Java calls using spring